# Where are images stored for Docker EE on Windows Server 2016 and how do I change its location?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-machine, windows-server-2016

Im running the latest Docker EE on server 2016, where are my images and containers stored on disk?

Running docker info I see this:

```
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
```

I have a csv volume mounted on the server and I want docker to use that volume for images and containers.

Where do I configure where docker stores and runs images and containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be controlled with the `--graph` option to `dockerd.exe` or by similarly modifying the `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json` file. Details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon#configure-docker-with-configuration-file

Comment: So what happens if I make that config change and restart the docker service? Do the images/containers in C:\ProgramData get moved to the new location? Does it copy them and leave them in the old location too?

Comment: No, you should move those yourself. If you change and restart and do nothing, Docker will just start over with no images